# MHL only works for a few minutes on Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, mhl

I picked up an [HML-to-HDMI adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009LAZG2M), and an [adapter to get it working on my Galaxy S4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089VO86Y).  When I first plug it into a TV, everything is great!  I can get a picture and sound on my TV in the expected resolutions.

After a few minutes, TV reports "no signal".  If I unplug the cable from either the TV end or the phone end, the phone reports the HDMI cable disconnected.  Plugging it back in on both ends, the phone reports that the HDMI cable is connected.  However, I still don't see anything on the TV.

Rebooting the phone (via holding the power button and choosing restart) does not resolve the issue.  If I plug the phone into a power source or USB port, and then switch back to the MHL adapter, it starts to work again.

This problem has occurred with multiple TVs.

I have a couple theories:

- Some sort of power management shuts off the video output after a few minutes.  (Note that I can be playing video and the phone screen stays on while TV reports no signal.)
- An error condition with the interface that requires it to reset.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Am I the only one with this problem?  If so, I suppose I could have a funky adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased 3 cheap MHL cables, same problem than you.  This is the red one.  2 cables disconnect all the time, one works perfectly.  The problem is the crappy cable.

Comment: Got a link to the cable that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Rocket Fish MHL-to-HDMI without issue in the past on a Note 4.  Your MHL adapter should have come with an additional input port in USB Micro formfactor.  Try plugging this into a power source as an auxilary power supplement, and see if the issue persists.  If you need to output to multiple displays, you may need to daisy chain another adapter onto the current one to supply adequate power to the peripherals.